# Is it possible to view the downloaded crossdomain.xml from SWF in AS3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

When attempting to download a remote resource from a SWF, it first downloads and checks the *crossdomain.xml* file located at the root of the web server (or at the location specified in `loadpolicyfile()`).  I'd like to access the downloaded *crossdomain.xml* file from within the SWF.  Where is this file stored and is it accessible from within the SWF?

I'm using this as a reachability mechanism: if the *crossdomain.xml* file is downloaded, the web server (which I know to be hosting a *crossdomain.xml* file) is reachable.  This web server might not allow from '`*`' in its policy file, preventing me from simply requesting a file elsewhere on the server to determine reachability.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this example which load the `crossdomain.xml` and verify the reachability of the server :

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.fb.com/crossdomain.xml')

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request)
    loader.addEventListener(
        Event.COMPLETE, 
        function(e):void { 
            trace('crossdomain file content : ')
            trace(loader.data)
        }
    )
    loader.addEventListener(
        HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, 
        function(e):void {
            //trace('http status: ' + e.status)
            if(e.status == 200){
                trace('this web server is reachable')
            }
        }
    )
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e){})
    loader.load(request)
```

Example with fb.com :

```
this web server is reachable
crossdomain file content : 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only" />
    <allow-access-from domain="s-static.facebook.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="static.facebook.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="*.static.ak.facebook.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="*.static.ak.fbcdn.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="s-static.ak.fbcdn.net" />
    <allow-access-from domain="*.static.ak.fbcdn.net" />
    <allow-access-from domain="s-static.ak.facebook.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="www.facebook.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="secure.facebook.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="static.ak.fbcdn.net" />
    <allow-access-from domain="www.latest.facebook.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="www.inyour.facebook.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="www.beta.facebook.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="m-static.ak.fbcdn.net" />
    <allow-access-from domain="fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net" />
    <allow-access-from domain="static.xx.fbcdn.net" />
    <allow-access-from domain="z-m-static.xx.fbcdn.net" />
    <allow-access-from domain="z-1-static.xx.fbcdn.net" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I hope that can help you.

Comment: What browser did you execute this in?  I had tried using HTTP_STATUS events and from what I can tell, browsers always return a status of 0.

Comment: @zretep I tested it in many browsers : firefox, chrome and opera and I think 0 is the default value of `HTTPStatusEvent.status` so may be flash didn't load any thing as security problem, try to add an `SecurityErrorEvent` listener to your `URLLoader`.

Comment: @zretep Adobe talking about the 0 : "... An HTTPStatusEvent object does not necessarily indicate an error condition; it simply reflects the HTTP status code (if any) that is provided by the networking stack. Some Flash Player environments may be unable to detect HTTP status codes; a status code of 0 is always reported in these cases.".

Comment: Every browser I've tested returns zero.  You said you tested in FF, Chrome, and Opera...what versions (or what version of flash)?  "this web server is reachable" should never be displayed in the code you provided.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on sites that don't allow from `*`.  This is why I want to access the policy file that the SWF requests **before** I make my request with `URLLoader()`.  Otherwise, the sandboxing prevents me from even requesting the _crossdomain.xml_ file itself.

Comment: I think that your are testing with a local file that's why you got 0. For security reason, you can not access to an online location so you should authorize your local swf file to do using [Global Security Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) or using the flash configuration on your windows control panel the advanced tab > location approved params and add your swf file. I think if the security config of your swf authorize it to access to an crossdomain file so it can do despite the file dont contain "*", fb.com is the proof

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for a solution that doesn't require modifying settings to alter the sandbox.  This might be as good as it gets.